# How to download Kafka in VM

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am trying to setup Kafka in vm (EC2 instance).

I am trying to download with wget. But it is not downloading just not giving any error but downloading completed in just 2 seconds. If I check in folder (using ls) I am seeing like this:

```
closer.cgi?path=%2Fkafka%2F2.7.0%2Fkafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz'
'closer.cgi?path=%2Fkafka%2F2.7.0%2Fkafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz.1'
'closer.cgi?path=%2Fkafka%2F2.7.0%2Fkafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz.2'
'closer.cgi?path=%2Fkafka%2F2.7.0%2Fkafka_2.13-2.7.0.tgz.3'
```

I tried multiple times, Even I am getting same.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what your wget command looks like... The closer.cgi link from the Apache site is a redirect, not the actual Kafka tarball

Since you added a tag for ksqlDB, I'd suggest using Ansible, anyway - https://docs.confluent.io/ansible/current/overview.html

Or find the APT installation directions there in those docs